# Cypress-Xpath :: Error running with docker compose file

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Facing issue while running tests in cypress docker containers

in my case i want to use xpath to identify web-elements to automate our web-application i have successfully add cypress-xpath and able to run it in local but same code while running in docker i was facing below error

Error :
/cypress/support/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-xpath' in '/cypress/support'
resolve 'cypress-xpath' in '/cypress/support'

i have ref this https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath
working fine in local but facing issue in docker

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution
need to add below volumes and working dir in docker compose file

working_dir: /e2e

volumes:

- ./:/e2e

then it will work perfectly